# Return a function in a model - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my Users table I have the users `first_name` and `last_name` in a separate column.

On my main view, after the user is authenticated I want to display that users full name. I know I can do `Auth::user()->first_name`  `Auth::user()->last_name` but Id like a function that I can call example `fullname()` and it would return me those.

Do I specify that in the users table and can I call it using the `Auth::` class?

Comment: Do you want only for authenticated users or want to have in user model overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create function fullname in model like this:

```
public function fullname(){
    return $this->first_name . " " . $this->last_name;
}
```

You can access this: `Auth::user()->fullname();`

You can also use it with the User object.

Comment: Thank you,  I was thinking of this but didn't think it was the correct way!

Comment: @Victori Check out Laravel's Accessor and Mutators concept. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators This is pretty handy and useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach of Attribute in model

```
class User extends Model {

    public function getFullNameAttribute() {
        return ucfirst($this->first_name) . ' ' . ucfirst($this->last_name);
    }

}
```

You can use like this

```
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->full_name;
```

OR

```
Auth::user()->full_name;
```